# Best CMS to handle short snippets of text?

Tags: search, cms, snippet

I have to install a CMS to manage a set of mathematical problems, i.e., our main content will be short (~3 lines) snippets of text. We need the ability to add comments and categories/tags, possibly with a powerful search function combining different constraints on the categories.

A crucial ability is the possibility to combine the results of a search in the same page to produce a (printable) problem sheet: not many CMS's seem to be able to do so, and it is difficult for me to test every one for this specific function. Do you guys know of a CMS that is capable to return formatted search result in this fashion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).  As it can support all of this quite easily.  Drupal is a bit of a mix between CMS and web framework.  It has a bit of a learning curve but it's very flexible and once mastered can be leveraged to solve almost any use case.

Just add a new content type "problem" or whatever you want to call it.  You can use [Content Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck) to add additional custom fields that you wish to capture.

The Comment module is part of core...so just enable it and allow comments on this content type.

Taxonomy is also part of core so enable it and use it for tagging.  There are many additional taxonomy modules that add some features and help manage these.

Search is in Core.

[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) can be used to generate a problem sheet.

That should get you going in the right direction but Drupal is a big subject and there are a ton of [modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules) available.

Comment: Also, if you're working with Math, the Drutex Drupal module makes it dead simple to have very nicely-rendered equasions in your content.

Answer (score 0):

Any CMS shall do. But I love http://textpattern.org, for syntax highlighter and snippets use SyntaxHighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter). It's a javascripts! So, Any CMS shall do.